# d3.js: pan with limits

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a basic linear chart with pan functionality.

I managed to limit the extent to which the chart elements can be dragged by limiting the `d3.event.translate` values:

```
var tx = Math.max(0, d3.event.translate[0]),
    ty = Math.min(0, d3.event.translate[1]);
```

All I need now is to limit the x and y axes accordingly. See the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Q2SWV/

The bars on the chart are limited by 0 when dragging down or to the left. The x and y axes aren't. Any ideas on how to fix the axis problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're very close, but you're missing the final step of updating the `zoom` behavior with your updated translation coordinates. This will fix your problem since both axes are updated using the `zoom`. Add the following right after determining `tx` and `ty`:

```
zoom.translate([tx, ty]);
```

This will apply the limits to your axes. See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/nZD3E/.

Comment: i know this was a long time ago, but this only has the limit on 2 sides, i.e x[0], y[0], how do i do it so from all 4 sides ? for example, i can only go in the y direction between 0 and 100, and same with x ?

Comment: This example does not work (don't know if caused by a newer d3 version).