# How do I limit the panning on a force directed graph layout without axis ? D3/JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There is a question here

[d3.js: pan with limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141721/d3-js-pan-with-limits)

Answering the question to limiting the pan movement. But this uses axis, which I do not have.

What I have is a force directed graph which has the ability to pan and zoom.

Now I have put a limit on the zoom using :

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw).scaleExtent([0.8, 2]))
```

I am wondering how do I go about limiting the pan movement of this graph so i dont drag the network/graph outside of the viewport.

(The network may change size depending on the JSON file imported, so I can't use exact figures)

```
inner.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
```

Comment: In the `zoom` event handler, check whether the current translation is outside of the extent you want to limit it to and if it is don't apply it to the SVG.

Comment: so how do you do that ? @LarsKotthoff

Comment: That's what @Elijah is doing in his answer.

Comment: okay. i see. he's put "The rest of your redraw function, now using the updated translate on your zoom". how do i apply that to mine : "inner.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); " ? ? @LarsKotthoff

Comment: It's all in the answer, you just need to add the scale part.

Comment: If you have issues with an answer, please comment on that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent zoom.extent. You can override zoom's translate with mins and maxes inside your redraw function, though. For instance, if you wanted to limit zoom to stay within 500px of its original position:

```
function redraw() {

 var oldT = yourZoom.translate()
 var newT = [0,0]
 newT[0] = Math.max(-500,oldT[0]);
 newT[0] = Math.min(500,oldT[0]);
 newT[1] = Math.max(-500,oldT[0]);
 newT[1] = Math.min(500,oldT[0]);
 yourZoom.translate(newT);

//The rest of your redraw function, now using the updated translate on your zoom

}
```

Comment: i cant seem to figure it out. i have "inner.attr("transform","translate(" + newT + ")" + "scale("+ d3.event.scale +")"); " but that only moves diagonal but the boundries work. What am i doing wrong ? :( @Elijah

Comment: Put the whole thing up on jsFiddle or gist.github.com and it'll be easier for us to take a look and figure it out.