# Limiting D3 treemap Panning

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have implemented a zooming treemap using D3.js. The treemap can be zoomed and panned I have limited the zooming function but cant limit the pan of the map. I want the panning to be only be inside the map rather than outside of it.

This is the current working implementation of my treemap : http://www.advbizclan.com/treemapt/

I want it like the zooming function which is only limited to the map the panning should also be limited only to the map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3.js: pan with limits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24141721/d3-js-pan-with-limits)

Comment: The above link i tried which only limits to one side of the treemap. 

I want somewhat like this http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-worldmap-boilerplate.html any idea on how to limit the panning like the link given with my treemap ?

Comment: set up a jsfiddle and ill show you.

Comment: I cant seem to set it up on jsfiddle as i am uploading the same code as the url i gave you in my previous comment.

https://jsfiddle.net/fz5gre38/

Please review if i am missing out something.

Comment: did the answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your fiddle was the `LoadType` was incorrect. To fix this just click the `Javascript` button at the top of the Javascript window, and select `No wrap- in <body>` in the `LOAD TYPE`.

As for your problem. It's fairly simple. At the moment, you have this for your panning and zooming of your treemap :

```
.call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 3]).on("zoom", function() {
      console.log(d3.event.translate)
      chart.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
```

This uses the `d3.event.translate` to translate your `svg`. But you only want to pan in the `y` direction yes ? As `d3.event.translate`returns an array of x and y coordinates, and the translate takes an x and y coordinate to translate by, just pass 0 for the x and `d3.event.translate[1]` (i.e the y coordinate) to the translate like so :

```
.on("zoom", function() {
        chart.attr("transform", function(d) {
          console.log(d3.event.translate);
          return "translate(" + [0, d3.event.translate[1]] + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"
        })
      }))
```

Now for the extent. You need to add limits to this, for my example I have just done this (you can easily implement your own limits) :

```
 if(d3.event.translate[1] > 0 && d3.event.translate[1] < chartHeight/2 ){
          console.log('move')
          return "translate(" + [0, d3.event.translate[1]] + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")";
          }
```

Here, you cant drag the map up, but you can drag it down half way.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/w7em39wj/

Comment: http://finviz.com/map.ashx this treemap is what i want in which only when you zoom you can pan the map which is limited to the domain of the map can you help me in making the same functionality ? We are close to achieve this i think.

Comment: You asked for one thing before and now you asking for another!! ??

Comment: No bro you got me wrong i found this link yesterday which is the exact same thing i needed the link above would have helped mee too its the same thing just the panning is limited on both x and y and when you zoom then only you could drag the map within the limited domain.